# fire after update trigger if the updated column value is equal to 'APPROVED'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i had two  table named  test and test_audit.i had a status column in test table 
if i updated the status column in test table with value 'APPROVED' then only the after update trigger will be fired.i want query to create trigger
(if i update status except 'APPROVED' the trigger will not fire)

Comment: And your question is? Have tried something?

Comment: The trigger always fires.  Put an `if` in the trigger.

Comment: @gordon linoff thank you for the information but i don't know how apply if clause in trigger.if it possible please write the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't control whether the trigger will be fired or not, but you can control what will happen inside the trigger.

You should be aware that triggers are fired based on statements, not on rows, so be careful not to assume the inserted table will only contain one row.

That being said, your trigger might look something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tr_Test ON dbo.Test FOR UPDATE
AS

    INSERT INTO test_audit (Id, Name, [Status], [time stamp])
    SELECT Id, Name, [Status], GETDATE()
    FROM Inserted I
    WHERE I.[Status] = 'APPROVED'
    AND EXISTS
    (
         SELECT 1
         FROM Deleted D
         WHERE D.Id = I.Id -- assuming primary key column is called id...
         AND D.[Status] <> 'APPROVED'
    )
```

Comment: not working boss

Comment: Of course, I don't know your tables structure and your goal, I'm just showing you how can you check inside the trigger that the column callled `Status` was changed to `'APPROVED'`... If you want a tailor-made solution you will have to give out more details

Comment: test table has ID,Name,Status columns and ID is Identity column.table audit also having same columns in addition of time stamp column

Comment: I've edited my answer based on your last comment.